# Is using airplane mode an acceptable way to test a lack of connection?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

We are in the process of developing an method of caching so that our app can continue to operate in an area with very little/no signal. 
Obviously users will try to continue to use functions that require data and we need to handle the inevitable failure of these requests appropriately.

Essentially we are sat in the office, switching airplane mode on and off to simulate entering/exiting signal then adjusting our app to fix any issues this may arise.

What I'd like to know is, **is using airplane mode going to give us a reasonable simulation of entering/exiting an area with no data or are there other implications?**

I've seen [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592150/monotouch-webrequest-connection-fails-after-switching-off-airplane-mode-on-iphon) raising the issue that the 3G/EDGE connection may not always wake up after airplane mode is switched on - while I appreciate this method is **no way** as good as actually being out in the field testing, if we can get a reasonable simulation and account for the majority of the problems that arise then I think this is an acceptable tradeoff.

I apologise if this has been asked before, I did do a search on here & on google but couldn't find any appropriate results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try the [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/)

[image]

There is a WWDC 2012 session called [Networking Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=706) that mentions it (but he does not explain how to use it there).

---

To get it, you have to go to [XCode/Open Developer Tool/More Developer Tools..](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#) and download the latest Hardware IO Tools for XCode.

[image]

Once you install it from the IO Tools pkg, "Network Link Conditioner" will appear in System Preferences

You can then do something like 100% packet loss to simulate one of those routers that pretends you are connected but actually doesn't work.

[image]

On iOS, the network link conditioner is under [Settings / Developer](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2012/09/ios6-network-link-conditioner/) (you must have enabled Developer mode in XCode first to see it)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that in the Airplane Mode the networking operations fail fast, while spotty mobile signal will lead to timeouts and a-few-bytes-an-hour speeds. This is usually a significant difference from the UI viewpoint. (It might be worth a try to use some bandwidth throttle to starve the testing machine and see how it behaves when the network starts to break?)

Comment: I've tried to restrict the bandwidth using a variety of programs but have had limited success. I feel this may be due to the fact I'm using OS X 10.6 Server edition?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Pulling the plug on your router should be reasonably close, still better than the Airplane Mode.

Comment: I currently remote desktop into the mac via a windows machine so we've opted to simply turn on some firewall rules that don't allow any connections to the internet, seems to work just as well. Thanks.

Comment: I used [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to do network testing for my last iPhone app. It helped me find a few issues that only cropped up with slow/spotty connections.

Answer (score 2):

A few years back, when testing remote devices which used the cell network to communicate with the 'home base', we did things like move them into a shielded room (make shift), place large shields on three of four sides to force them to connect to a certain tower (and therefore, network), etc. Brute force physical methods. Since this actually cuts off the signal, it may be a more realistic approach.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea - as we're design exclusively for the iphone 4 (it's an enterprise app so backwards compatability isn't an issue) we could use utilize the "Death Grip". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try this through your wlan-router. First, disable data roaming on your iPhone. Then, let the iPhone be connected to the internet through your wlan network. Then, disconnect the gateway on your wlan router while your iPhone is still connected to the wlan network.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what failure modes you are trying to test.

I use Airplane mode as a first pass check to make sure an app submission isn't quickly rejected.

Other network failure handling checks might include:

- 3G only (no wifi).
- WIFI only (in Airplane mode).
- Pulling the power cord on the WIFI access point.
- Pulling the network cable from the back of the WIFI access point after connecting to it (Reachability may falsely say yes).
- Walking in and out of a basement
  elevator (or other Faraday cage) in the middle of a transfer.
- Driving between 2 cell towers during a data transfer.
- Walking between 2 enabled WIFI access points between connection and data transfer.
- Starting the app after more than 30 minutes of device inactivity (radios may be idle).
- Running the app while another app (Safari, Mail) is downloading in the background.
- etc.