# How to use StartWWAN

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Our app uses RestSharp which uses `HttpWebRequest` under the covers.

When switching from wifi to 3g or from airplane mode to 3g, we lose connection - we can no longer make http calls using RestSharp.

I understand this is a problem with the mono http implementation on iOS and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592150/monotouch-webrequest-connection-fails-after-switching-off-airplane-mode-on-ipho) the way to solve it is to use `StartWWAN`.

Currently I'm calling `StartWWAN` whenever I detect that network connectivity has changed. While I'm calling it, I'm making sure I don't perform any http requests.

It works only when my phone is connected to a power source. It doesn't work when it's not.

Can someone please explain when am I supposed to call `StartWWAN`?